# One command to kill a process using a specific port

Tags: python, process, port, kill, lsof

For a project, I constantly need to find the process using a specific port and kill that process. I do this by:

```
lsof -i :portnumber
#read the pid
kill -9 pid
```

Since I do this a lot, I'm a bit bored to do so. So, I wonder if there is a way to kill a process using a specific port with **only one** command? 
If not, is there a python command that returns the pid of the process using a specific port, so that I can write a simple script to make the work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems like a job for a shell command, eg:

```
lsof -i :80 | awk '{print $2}' | tail -1 | kill -9
```

Although if you really wanted to do it in python, you could wrap that command using the `subprocess` module: [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html)